# Generating Output for Simulink Model

Tags: simulink

I have a simulink model. It initially had an algebraic loop but even after adding delay, I am not able to produce any output.

I am representing an equation of the form y(t+1) = 3*y(t). 
[image: Feedback Simulink Model]

What should I change to get output of the scope?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `initial condition` of the `Unit Delay`.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/16389397)

Comment: Yes it does.  The answer to "What should I change to get output of the scope?" is "the initial condition of the unit delay".  Succinct, and 100% accurate.  Not all answers need to be lengthy.  I didn't leave a comment because I am not giving a critique or requesting clarification.